# Does a retained Fragment retain its View?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentmanager

Calling `Fragment.setRetainInstance(true)` will cause the `Fragment` to be retained by the `FragmentManager`, but is it's `View` retained? I think not, but I'm looking for confirmation. I think not because `Fragment.onCreateView()` is still called (even though `onCreate()` isn't) and calling `getView()` returns `null`.

What is the point of retaining a `Fragment` across configuration changes if its `View`s aren't? One reason is to retain data, to avoid expensive reloads, but there are other ways to do that.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Does a retained Fragment retain its View?

That depends on how you define it. The fragment will have `onCreateView()` called again, and so it is supposed to set up its UI for the new activity. However, if you have field holding onto widgets, those fields are retained, and it is your job to have those fields point to the new widgets, to avoid memory leaks and other problems.

> What is the point of retaining a Fragment across configuration changes if its Views aren't?

To retain data, to avoid expensive reloads.

> but there are other ways to do that

Only with limits.

For example, all else being equal, it is better to retain data via the saved instance state `Bundle`. However, that `Bundle` cannot hold onto arbitrary objects (e.g., a `Camera`), and there is a ~1MB limit on the size of the `Bundle`, so it cannot hold onto large objects (e.g., a photo).

Part of the reason for the term "retain" is that retained fragments build atop the old `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()` callback on `Activity`. That is now `final` and cannot be used, IIRC.

Data whose life is broader than the current activity can be cached globally (e.g., POJO cache for database/network I/O results, image cache). However, some things, like a `Camera`, do not belong in static data members like that.

Stuff you retrieve using the `Loader` framework (e.g., via `CursorLoader`) is automatically retained, but the `Loader` framework has its own issues for things other than `CursorLoader`.

You don't *have* to use a retained fragment. I find them reasonably useful.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use `setRetainInstance` on non-UI fragments (that do not implement `onCreateView`). I delegate lengthy operations (api calls on a server for example) so that they still happen during a configuration change (screen rotation) and when my UI comes back up I can just connect back to the retained fragment for the result/progress.